# JPA,RELATIONSHIP BEGINEER MANY TO MANY with some complexity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have 4 Entities in My domain model which is an Professor College Department and Role.
The use case are

1. Professor can only work for one college which makes One to Many
   Relation ship (College -> Professor)
2. Professor will have a Many Roles at college level (Admin, Food Inspector ??)
3. Professor can work for many departments (Many to Many)
4. In each department professor may have a different role

   ```
   class Professor {
       @ManyToOne
       private College workingWithCollege;
       @JoinTable(name = "professor_college_role",
                  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "professor_id"),
                  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
       @OneToMany
       private Collection<Role> roles;
    }

   class College {

   }


   class Department {

   }

   class DepartMentRole {
       @ManyToOne
       private Department department;
       @ManyToOne
       private Role role;
       //TODO: Dont know how exactly to solve this
   }

   class ProfessorDepartmentRole {
        @OneToOne
        private Professor professor;
        @OneToMany
        private Collection DepartmentRole;
   }
   ```

DO we really need Department Role how to connect a professor to a department and a role for that department

Comment: Is the set of college level roles, different from the set of department roles?

Comment: No its same but in real world the services offered for that roles are different

Comment: Can you just create the DepartmentRole class then, have another many to many relationship between professor and DepartmentRole?

Comment: Do you think the code provided above is good enough or u will do it in different way ??

Comment: Others might be able to advise differently, but I'd have to test it out and I don't have the resources to do that right now. Try it out, you can always come back to this post if you have more questions about the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert the ProfessorDepartmentRole class to a Many to Many (as suggested by KLibby). So to answer your question, we do retain the DepartmentRole class. Also, then you can remove the collection roles from Professor class since you can derive the roles via the 2 join tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement the relationship between the entities involved and their mappings.

You define you entities: `College`, `Professor`, `Department` and `Role`

Now the problem is how you define the relationship between `Professor` working for `Department` in a particular `Role`. One way to do is to represent this relationship as another Entity - let's call this `ProfessorDepartment`.

The many-to-many relationship between `Professor` and `Department` entities can still be logically represented using `ProfessorDepartment` acting as a **"relationship state"/"association class"** between the 2 entities as illustrated in the ff. mappings:

- relationship from `Professor` to `ProfessorDepartment` is one-to-many
- relationship from `ProfessorDepartment` to `Professor` is many-to-one (bi-directional)
- relationship from `Department` to `ProfessorDepartment` is one-to-many
- relationship from `ProfessorDepartment` to `Department` is many-to-one (bi-directional)

Now that we have encapsulated  the "relationship state" into an entity named ProfessorDepartment, we can now have a reference to the Role entity. Assuming that there is only one role for a given `Professor`-`Department` relationship, we can map this as one-to-one.

Here's a class diagram to illustrate the relationship between Department, Professor and Role.

[image]

Here's the data model:
[image]

Here are codes of each entity to illustrate all of that explanation:

```
@Entity
public class College implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="COLLEGE_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college")
    private List<Professor> professorList = new ArrayList<Professor>(); 
...
}

@Entity
public class Professor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PROF_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="professor")
    private List<ProfessorDepartment> profDepartmentList = new ArrayList<ProfessorDepartment>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COLLEGE_ID")
    private College college;
...
}

@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="DEPT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private List<ProfessorDepartment> profDepartmentList = new ArrayList<ProfessorDepartment>();
...
}

@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PROFESSOR_DEPARTMENT")
@IdClass(ProfessorDepartmentId.class)
public class ProfessorDepartment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
    private Department department;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PROF_ID")
    private Professor professor;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;
...
}

public class ProfessorDepartmentId implements Serializable {

    private Long department;

    private Long professor;
...
}
```

Take note of the use of `@IdClass` annotation. `ProfessorDepartment` entity will have a composite primary key composed of `Professor` and `Department`'s primary keys.

Here's a sample scenario:

1. We have professors, John and Peter
2. They both work at Standford University
3. We have 3 Departments: Computer Dept, Finance Dept, Health Dept
4. John works as an accountant in Finance Dept
5. Peter works as a doctor in Health Dept
6. John and Peter both works in Computer Dept
7. John works as Computer Administrator, while Peter works as Support Specialist - both in Computer Department

Here's the code to illustrate that scenario:

```
    College college = new College();
    college.setName("Stanford University");

    em.persist(college);

    Professor profJohn = new Professor();
    profJohn.setCollege(college);
    profJohn.setName("John");
    college.getProfessorList().add(profJohn);

    em.persist(profJohn);

    Professor profPeter = new Professor();
    profPeter.setCollege(college);
    profPeter.setName("Peter");
    college.getProfessorList().add(profPeter);

    em.persist(profPeter);

    Department compDept = new Department();
    compDept.setName("Computer Department");

    em.persist(compDept);

    Department financeDept = new Department();
    financeDept.setName("Finance Department");

    em.persist(financeDept);

    Department healthDept = new Department();
    healthDept.setName("Health Department");

    em.persist(healthDept);

    Role accountantRole = new Role();
    accountantRole.setName("Accountant");

    em.persist(accountantRole);

    Role doctorRole = new Role();
    doctorRole.setName("Doctor");

    em.persist(doctorRole);

    Role compAdminRole = new Role();
    compAdminRole.setName("Computer Administrator");

    em.persist(compAdminRole);

    Role compSupport = new Role();
    compSupport.setName("Computer Support Specialist");

    em.persist(compSupport);

    // John works as an accountant in Finance Department
    ProfessorDepartment johnInFinanceDept = new ProfessorDepartment();
    johnInFinanceDept.setDepartment(financeDept);
    johnInFinanceDept.setProfessor(profJohn);
    johnInFinanceDept.setRole(accountantRole);
    profJohn.getProfDepartmentList().add(johnInFinanceDept);
    financeDept.getProfDepartmentList().add(johnInFinanceDept);

    em.persist(johnInFinanceDept);

    // Peter works as a doctor in Health Department
    ProfessorDepartment peterInHealthDept = new ProfessorDepartment();
    peterInHealthDept.setDepartment(healthDept);
    peterInHealthDept.setProfessor(profPeter);
    peterInHealthDept.setRole(doctorRole);
    profPeter.getProfDepartmentList().add(peterInHealthDept);
    healthDept.getProfDepartmentList().add(peterInHealthDept);

    em.persist(peterInHealthDept);

    // Both John and Peter works in Computer Department but they are of different roles
    // John works as Computer Administrator
    // Peter works as Computer Support Specialist
    ProfessorDepartment johnInCompDept = new ProfessorDepartment();
    johnInCompDept.setDepartment(compDept);
    johnInCompDept.setProfessor(profJohn);
    johnInCompDept.setRole(compAdminRole);
    profJohn.getProfDepartmentList().add(johnInCompDept);
    compDept.getProfDepartmentList().add(johnInCompDept);

    em.persist(johnInCompDept);

    ProfessorDepartment peterInCompDept = new ProfessorDepartment();
    peterInCompDept.setDepartment(compDept);
    peterInCompDept.setProfessor(profPeter);
    peterInCompDept.setRole(compSupport);
    profPeter.getProfDepartmentList().add(peterInCompDept);
    compDept.getProfDepartmentList().add(peterInCompDept);

    em.persist(peterInCompDept);
```

Complete code is shared in my [Github repo](https://github.com/balagueri21/sample-codes/tree/master/MappingRelationshipState).

Comment: There is one more requirement actually which says that a professor can have a role at College level and it will entirely different role which he performs at Department level

Comment: You can actually model that in the same manner as you would model a Professor-Department relationship - by having an association class. Multiplicity may vary according to your requirements.